# Deploy aangular 8 and springboot application in azure

Tags: angular, azure, spring-boot, azure-devops

I have two separate project of spring boot for back-end and angular 8 for front-end.
I want to deploy both the project into my azure portal.

Can you tell me how we can achieve the same ?

Comment: Refer https://medium.com/@k32y/spring-boot-deployment-on-azure-app-service-zero-code-approach-88305c8d0818

Comment: upvote if the answer helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked in to the Azure Devops project in Azure portal?

It will have a pre defined template to deploy application if you're not sure of how to deploy.

**Go to portal -> Search for Devops Projects -> Create New -> Select your Language and select where you want to deploy (Either AppService/Containers)**

and then change your source to the repository where you want to import the code to

Answer (score 0):

We are hosting Angular 8 front-end on a storage account. You can upload the dist folder directly or set up DevOps to build and deploy. Hosting a SPA in pure Storage is by far the cheapest and most performant way of running in Azure. You can check following article for the study.

https://medium.com/medialesson/best-way-to-host-a-single-page-application-spa-in-microsoft-azure-3e70cbd075c3